# Can't connect Arduino Yùn to local server

Tags: php, mysql, arduino

I am new to Arduino programming and have had a lot of problems getting my arduino yùn to connect to my local server. My goal is to be able to send temperature data from the arduino to phpmyadmin, but so far I haven't even been able to connect. This is the code I tried to test the connection with:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = {  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ip(192,168,240,126);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 240, 1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);

IPAddress server(127,0,0,1); // Change to your server ip

EthernetClient client;
int totalCount = 0;
int loopCount = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(4,HIGH);

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, gateway, subnet);
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("Ready");
}

char pageAdd[32];
void loop()
{
  if(loopCount < 30)
  {
    delay(1000);
  }
  else
  {
    loopCount = 0;
    sprintf(pageAdd,"/arduino.php?temp1=%d",totalCount);
    if(!getPage(server,pageAdd)) Serial.print("Fail ");
    else Serial.print("Pass ");
    totalCount++;
    Serial.println(totalCount,DEC);
  }    

  loopCount++;
}

byte getPage(IPAddress ipBuf,char *page)
{
  int inChar;
  char outBuf[128];

  Serial.print("connecting...");

  if(client.connect(ipBuf,80))
  {
    Serial.println("connected");

    sprintf(outBuf,"GET %s HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n",page);
    client.write(outBuf);
  } 
  else
  {
    Serial.println("failed");
    return 0;
  }

  int connectLoop = 0;

  while(client.connected())
  {
    while(client.available())
    {
      inChar = client.read();
      Serial.write(inChar);
      connectLoop = 0;
    }

    delay(10);
    connectLoop++;
        if(connectLoop > 1000)
        {
          Serial.println();
          Serial.println("Timeout");
          client.stop();
        }

      }

      Serial.println();

      Serial.println("disconnecting.");
      client.stop();

      return 1;
    }
```

Here is the .php file:

```
<?
    $temp1 = $HTTP_GET_VARS['temp1'];
?>
<html>
<body>
test server page<br>
<? echo('temp1 = ' . $temp1 . ' '); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm trying to do the same thing. I plug in the arduino and am able to access arduino.local, but once I try and configure it with my wifi ( i know i'm using the right wifi password ), it resets and then I can't get back to arduino.local again after that! Ultimately I'm just trying to read data and issue commands from my php website, but first I need to figure out how to connect the damn thing

Answer (score 1):

> IPAddress server(127,0,0,1);

This is your localhost address of your server. Change it to your IPv4 address of your server.